# random shuffle in php?

Tags: php, random, shuffle

I'm creating a lottery to pair up people. So I want a way to shuffle the strings in an array where no item ends up on the same place. (You can't pair up with yourself)

```
    public function shuffleSantas(){
    $query = $this->db->get('person');
    $givers = array();
    $recievers = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row):          
        $givers[] = $row->name;
        //here i want a random order, but no name can be on the same place as in $givers!
        $recievers[] = '';
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Maybe you can make 1 big array do a shuffle() on it and the split it in half ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`array_rand()`](http://www.php.net/array_rand).

Answer (score 3):

shuffle the array once and then pair up the first element with the second, the second with the third etc. and the last with the first.

Comment: That approach do not guarantee that single element will not pair with itself.

Comment: Awesomely elegant solution ! (also slightly edited to be able to upvote, as like @J0HN I thought it was wrong)

Answer (score 1):

```
$src = $query->result();
$givers = array();
$receivers = array();
foreach ($src as $idx=>$first_person){
    $count = 0; //infinite loop guard
    do{
        ++$count;
        $sec_idx = rand(0,count($src)-1);
        $second_person = $src[$sec_idx];
    } while ($second_person==$first_person && $count<5); 
    $givers[] = $first_person;
    $receivers[] = $second_person; 
}
```

In this case one will be able to receive from one person and to give to other person. Is it OK? Also, this algorithm is not optimal and will definitely fall into infinity loop if there is only one person in an array.

Comment: And what happens when the result is odd ?

Comment: I think you got it wrong: each person is a giver **and** a receiver. Using your function, there is as many gift as number of people. And it the number of people is odd, one will not have any gift.

Comment: @Clement Updated a bit, always mixed that condition in `do ... while` loop. @Vince completely rewritten the code, now it definitely works.

Answer (score -2):

If think there is no built-in function in PHP to shuffle that way. You have to write your own function.

Comment: Indeed, however that question seemed too "pls give me the code"ish to raise a better answer, doesn't it ?